# Sitecore preserving old urls

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I changed the item name and hence its url. Published the site, but I see that the item is still accessible via its old url and also the new url.

Also, rebuilt the link database and cleaned up all databases. Still the item is available through both the urls. Any idea?

Using sitecore 7.0 MVC

Comment: Have you published parent item with subitems?

Comment: Yes! did full site publish

Comment: login to sitecore desktop, switch master to web and check if the old item is still there

Comment: Nope the item name reflect the name.

Comment: I meant to say the item name reflects the new name. Not sure why it is still accessible via the old name/url

Comment: Do you implement your own LinkProvider? also do you clear cache on publish?

Comment: Please check Item name and Item Display Name, aren't they same?

Comment: I agree on checking the name vs. display name. Also, when you did the publish, did you do a smart publish or incremental?

Comment: Finally managed to expire old urls by doing full site republish. After doing so, only new urls were in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a full site Republish to expire old urls. According to Sitecore Item urls do not change upon rename unless they are Republished.